# how can we develop ajax application with GWT UI-Binder

Tags: ajax, gwt, uibinder

As per my project requirement i want to develop an Ajax application with GWT Ui-Binder.. for achieving page refreshing automatically while getting content from database..

Remember: withOut  click Refresh button (or) any mouse motion.If u aware about this task...can you please give me with any related exmaple..

Answer (score 0):

if you want to refresh automatic, so you may have any condition where you get event of getting data from database like rpc came on **success** method etc.. then simply call  `Window.Location.refresh();` there.